# Trying to convert specific Json with JSON.NET gives me Error Converting Value

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am actually implementing some new functionality for my company's app, the previous dev already did some similar deserialization with JSON.NET successfully and I was trying to make it work with my new functionality.

Here is the object I am trying to deserialize:

```
"{
 \"@type\":[\"IN.history.1\"],
 \"@self\":\"/history\",
 \"history\":[
  \"195166208;
  2021-09-06T11:48:26.164;
  User Modified;
  TA_NONE;
  1.1.System.4.1;
  \\u0003D\\u0001 = \\u0001\\n\\u0006 = Standard\\nIsMandatory = No\\nModifiedUser_ID = 3\\nModifiedUser_Name = BIS Benutzer\\nModifierUser_ID = 3\\nModifierUser_Name = BIS Benutzer\\nSource_Name = RPS\\nSource_ReportingNumber = 0\\n\"
 ]
}"
```

To be able to store it I created two classes:

```
        public class HistoryList
        {
            public string eventID { get; set; }
            public string timestamp { get; set; }
            public string eventName { get; set; }
            public string ta { get; set; }
            public string siid { get; set; }
            public string parameters { get; set; }
        }

        public class GetHistory
        {
            public List<string> type { get; set; }
            public string self { get; set; }
            public List<HistoryList> history { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is my call to the deserialization method:

```
        internal List<HistoryList> GetHistory(int maxEvents)
        {
            string response = GetJson(_url + "/history?maxevents=" + Convert.ToString(maxEvents));
            response = response.Replace("@", "");
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MAP5000Classes.GetHistory>(response).history;
        }
```

I already noticed I had to get rid of the @, but I still get a conversion error with my class HistoryList(Could not cast or convert from System.String to HistoryList.), I probably made some mistake with my class...

Help would be much appreciated !

Comment: Your c# implies that `history` should be a list / array of objects of type `HistoryList`.  However your JSON contains an array containing one long string.  It should be an array of objects, where those objects include the properties expected for this `HistoryList` type.

Comment: `history` may look object-like, but in fact does not contain any JSON objects and really is just an array of strings. If you want to break those down further, some more manual parsing is needed (split on semicolons, trim, that sort of stuff). Alternatively, the other end that's doing the serializing might be compelled to make its output a little friendlier to deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot deserialize `HistoryList` like that. It's just an array containing a single string, there is no inherent meaning in them being particular properties. Instead you will have to parse it out manually:

```cs
public class GetHistory
{
    public List<string> type { get; set; }
    public string self { get; set; }
    public List<string> history { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
var history = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MAP5000Classes.GetHistory>(response);
var strings = history.history[0].Split(new[]{';', '\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
return new HistoryList {
    eventID = strings[0],
    timestamp = strings[1],
    eventName = strings[2],
    ta = strings[3],
    siid = strings[4],
    parameters = strings[5],
};
```